# Unexpected recursion step in beginner C exercise

Tags: c, recursion

I'm writing a beginner-level recursive function that finds a path through a given 12x12 labyrinth. I have a separate function for calculating the initial position (number of the initial square), but in this task the position is given, it's square 59. The function `mazeTraverse` calculates `x` and `y` based on position of the pathfinder, turns `maze[y][x]` into `" x "` and then calls itself to change the position according to what's around it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void mazeTraverse(char *[][12], int);

int main()
{
    char *labyrinth[12][12] = {{" # ", " # ", " # ", " # ", " # ", " # ", " # ", " # ", " # ", " # ", " # ", " # "},
                               {" # ", " . ", " . ", " . ", " # ", " . ", " . ", " . ", " . ", " . ", " . ", " # "},
                               {" . ", " . ", " # ", " . ", " # ", " . ", " # ", " # ", " # ", " # ", " . ", " # "},
                               {" # ", " # ", " # ", " . ", " # ", " . ", " . ", " . ", " . ", " # ", " . ", " # "},
                               {" # ", " . ", " . ", " . ", " . ", " # ", " # ", " # ", " . ", " # ", " . ", " . "},
                               {" # ", " # ", " # ", " # ", " . ", " # ", " . ", " # ", " . ", " # ", " . ", " # "},
                               {" # ", " . ", " . ", " # ", " . ", " # ", " . ", " # ", " . ", " # ", " . ", " # "},
                               {" # ", " # ", " . ", " # ", " . ", " # ", " . ", " # ", " . ", " # ", " . ", " # "},
                               {" # ", " . ", " . ", " . ", " . ", " . ", " . ", " . ", " . ", " # ", " . ", " # "},
                               {" # ", " # ", " # ", " # ", " # ", " # ", " . ", " # ", " # ", " # ", " . ", " # "},
                               {" # ", " . ", " . ", " . ", " . ", " . ", " . ", " # ", " . ", " . ", " . ", " # "},
                               {" # ", " # ", " # ", " # ", " # ", " # ", " # ", " # ", " # ", " # ", " # ", " # "}};
    int startingLocation = 59;
    
    mazeTraverse(labyrinth, startingLocation);

    return 0;
}

void mazeTraverse(char *maze[][12], int position)
{
    int y, x, exCounter, inCounter;
    
    y = position / 12;
    x = position % 12;
    
    maze[y][x] = " x ";
    
    for (exCounter = 0; exCounter <= 11; ++exCounter) {
        for (inCounter = 0; inCounter <= 11; ++inCounter)
            printf("%s", maze[exCounter][inCounter]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
        
    printf("Position: %d\n", position);
    printf("x: %d, y: %d\n\n", x, y);
    
    if (maze[y - 1][x] == " # " && maze[y][x - 1] != " # ")
        mazeTraverse(maze, position - 1);
    if (maze[y - 1][x] == " . " && maze[y][x + 1] != " . ")
        mazeTraverse(maze, position - 12);                  // Up until this point everything goes as it should
    if (maze[y - 1][x] != " . " && maze[y + 1][x] != " # ") // This if statement is the root of the problem
        mazeTraverse(maze, position + 12);
    
}
```

I'm yet to finish writing this function and I'm not asking for a solution. If you execute this code, you'll notice that after the pathfinder makes the first left turn and goes down until it encounters a `" # "`, it then jumps from square 41 to square 34, which is inside the far right tunnel, and starts going down from there. I tried reformulating the third `if` statement inside `mazeTraverse`, but it always jumps either to square 34, 46, or 70. Why does it make the jump? How does it make it? How to prevent that?

Comment: You should compare strings with `strcmp()`, notwith `==`.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that. However, I prefer not to use functions that my textbook hasn't mentioned, and it hasn't said anything about functions of string.h.

Comment: Actually, you should just store the 'center' char (as a `char` instead of `char*`)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'center' char, could you please elaborate?

Comment: @GBFZ well you could use (char) '#' instead of (char*) " # ".

Comment: it's more efficient to only store whatever is needed. (Also, `char` is smaller than a pointer in bytes.) For example, what if you want to output without whitespaces? Then you'll have to access all second elements to print them. Or what if you want a `|`, `-` and `+` between them? You'll still have to make a loop-based function for that anyway. In this case, you want `__` between them.

Comment: Thanks, I've changed that up. The problem with the recursion persists, though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some future generations of C learners will need this. Here's a block of `if` statements that made the function work properly. Apparently the answer to my question was putting `return` infront of every recursive call.

```
if (maze[y - 1][x] != " . " && maze[y][x - 1] == " . ")
    return mazeTraverse(maze, position - 1);
if (maze[y - 1][x] != " . " && maze[y + 1][x] != " # ")
    return mazeTraverse(maze, position + 12);
if (maze[y + 1][x] == " # " && maze[y][x - 1] != " . " && maze[y][x + 1] != " # ")
    return mazeTraverse(maze, position + 1);
if (maze[y - 1][x] == " . ")
    return mazeTraverse(maze, position - 12);
```

Comment: You shouldn't compare string literals with the `==` operator, as the compiler may decide not to merge string literals and in that case, comparisons may fail. And you might check for board bounds, in order to use `y - 1` or `y + 1` in array scritps.